# Passing array through a function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call a function to process some data in an array, I will be duplicating this for lots of different reasons, so just want to get the basic foundations right and I'm getting errors with data types. I've simplified my code to try and get it going from the ground up but still can't find the cause.

```
 Sub VBA_Split_Print()
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("J2:AE90000").ClearContents
    For J = 2 To last_row
        Dim arr() As String
        arr = Split(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(J, 9).Value, ",")
        Call ElectiveAdd(arr)
    Next J
 End Sub


Function ElectiveAdd(ByRef arr() As String)
    
    Dim arrLength As Integer
    arrLength = UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1)
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0
    For i = 24 To (arrLength + 24)
        Worksheets("Raw").Cells(J, i).Value = arr(x)
        x = x + 1
       Next i

End Function
```

When I'm trying to run this I am getting an Run-Time Error '1004' Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error message.

So revised code due to feedback and I feel that J is another issue so I have excluded it, thanks for pointing out the error though!

```
Sub VBA_Split_Print()
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
    Range("J2:AE90000").ClearContents
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(2, 9).Value, ",")
    Call ElectiveAdd(arr)
End Sub

Function ElectiveAdd(ByRef arr() As String)
    
    Dim arrLength As Integer
    arrLength = UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1)
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0
    For i = 24 To (arrLength + 24) + 1
        Worksheets("Raw").Cells(2, i).Value = arr(x)
        x = x + 1
       Next i

End Function
```

Now I am getting a different error message of subscript out of range, cell 2,9 = "[image]

Comment: Most likely `J` in `Worksheets("Raw").Cells(J, i).Value = arr(x)` = 0.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - so I've taken the loop out and made it focus on 2,9 instead, which contains the value "Happy,Dull,Priceless" so it should be returning an Array of 3 strings?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1) gives a value one less than the size of the array.  It should be arrLength = UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1)+1

Comment: I'm getting error code 400 when I run it from Excel with the button and Application defined error when I run it from within VBA console. In relation to which line it throws the error on, I believe it's to do with the call and the way the argument is defined in the function - but it could be something else - I'm not sure how to see the exact line.

Comment: Where have you declared `J`? What do you expect `J` to equal in `Worksheets("Raw").Cells(J, i).Value = arr(x)`? What happens if you add `Option Explicit` to the very top of the module? Does it flag `J` as an undeclared variable?

Comment: Good point - forgot about the J when splitting it... let me check if I can fix that

Comment: @BigBen I have removed J completely, I just want to be able to pass through the array and use it for the time being. I've updated the code to that effect, hope that clears things up.

Comment: Remove the `+ 1` from `For i = 24 To (arrLength + 24) + 1`

Comment: Thanks @Rory that actually worked, so think that resolves this one - now just to build it back up.

Comment: Note that VBA is a mess when it comes to 1-based or 0-based indexing in arrays. Here you assume the `Split()` function returns a 1-based array, which it might, or it might not. Also the row count should be `arrLength = UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1) + 1` as if the start and the end are the same there is still 1 row to process.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the array, why not pass the cell?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBA_Split_Print()
Dim last_row As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim arr() As String

    With Worksheets("Raw")
        last_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("J2:AE90000").ClearContents

        For I = 2 To last_row
            Call ElectiveAdd(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(I, 9))
        Next I

    End With
End Sub

Function ElectiveAdd(ByRef rng As Range)
Dim arr As Variant
Dim I As Long

    arr = Split(rng.Value, ",")

    For I = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, 24 + I).Value = arr(I)
    Next I

End Function
```

If you still want to pass the array you'll probably need to pass the row as well so the data goes in the right place.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBA_Split_Print()
Dim last_row As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim arr() As String

    With Worksheets("Raw")
        last_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("J2:AE90000").ClearContents

        For I = 2 To last_row
            arr = Split(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(I, 9), ",")
            Call ElectiveAdd(arr, I)
        Next I

    End With
End Sub

Function ElectiveAdd(ByRef arr As Variant, rw As Long)
Dim I As Long

    For I = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        Worksheets("Raw").Cells(rw, 24 + I).Value = arr(I)
    Next I

End Function
```